# Facebook login and access user info titanium

Tags: facebook-graph-api, titanium, facebook-login

I have a app in titanium and i want facebook login and accessing user info such as email, first name , last name , DOB through fb login.. how can i do this?

Comment: Appcelerator has an excellent documentation on that: http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Modules.Facebook

Answer (score 0):

This method would help you getting the data.Use this after you logged in from facebook

```
function getFacebookInfo(){
    Titanium.Facebook.requestWithGraphPath('me', {}, 'GET', function(e){
        if (e.success){
            var jsonObject  = JSON.parse(e.result);
            //do something here with these values. They cannot be passed out of this
            //function call... this is an asynchronous call
            //that is, do this:
            saveToDb(jsonObject.first_name);
        } else {
            //some sort of error message here i guess
        }
    });

};
```

Thanks